# Does the phrase "Did you grow up on a farm" disapprove of a person who does not act like a civilized man?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

A native English speaker lived in Wellesley, MA. in the USA said to a child.

"**Don't eat with your face in the bowl. Did you grow up on a farm?**"

[image: Person eating from a bowl]

Is "**Did you grow up on a farm?**" idiomatic when we disapprove of a person who does not act like a civilized man?

Comment: The implication is obviously that she is eating like an animal, but I've never heard the expression used in that sense in British English. I have sometimes heard "Were you born in a barn?" when someone leaves the door open, letting the cold in.

Comment: My guess is that this is a combination of the more common idioms "were you raised in a barn" and "were you raised by wolves."  The meaning is the same as "were you raised by wolves" (i.e. *you have bad manners*).  It's similar enough to both of these well-established idioms that it took me a minute to realize that it wasn't the standard expression.

Comment: For pete's sake. Did you grow up on a farm is not an American idiom. It is just something some stupid person said. Now, there are idioms involving the word piggy or pig to mean eating sloppily. "Are you eating from a trough?"

Comment: The idiom is: to eat like a pig, in British and American English.

Comment: Suggest you edit your question to: civilized person and remove the word man there.

Comment: My father used to say "Good God, lad, you've got enough brown sauce on your dinner for three Irish navvies". Also, "We should have given you your meal in a trough" for the slightest thing. You will gather I don't like over-controlling fathers.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common idiom in American English. It is meant to be both dismissive of a person's manners as uncivilized, and to put down the person as being from a rural area, and not from the city.

Comment: This is simply not so.

Comment: So...what part is wrong? I'm curious how you are going to deny that I have heard it used this way, and that it is common.

Comment: Wait, I see you said something above. Yes, it is an American idiom -- apparently it is not a British one. It is something that someone said -- and says -- frequently. Going by the definition of idiom, it is idiomatic. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/idiom

Comment: I never said it was idiomatic. I said it was not an idiom, meaning: a set phrase.

Comment: Yup, it's a set phrase. I've heard it all my life.

Comment: correction: II never said it was not idiomatic.

Comment: Note: this is two native US speakers who are attesting this is an American idiom.

Comment: I only see you.

Comment: A native English speaker lived in Wellesley, MA. in the USA said to a child....this is from the top of the question you're commenting on!

Comment: Native AmE speaker and I've never heard "Did you grow up on a farm?" I've heard "Were you raised by wolves?" and "Were you raised in a barn?" but never "Did you grow up on a farm?" as a disparaging way to say someone doesn't know how to behave properly. There's nothing bad about the way farmers raise their children. I've lived in the city and in rural America, and frankly, I think the rural kids have better manners (in general) than the city kids do.

Comment: I'm not saying it's a nice or accurate thing to say. I'm just saying that I've heard it.